# UIImageView one of cell contentView's views is not expanding along with its parent view

Tags: iphone, ios, uiview, uitableview, uiimageview

I have a UITableView where each cell contains one UIView in its contentView, let's call it V.
V also has subViews, one UIImageView and UILabel.UIImage is just a white rounded rectangle 
I want my cell (along with UIImageView) to expand and shrink when selected. I added some code to didSelectRowAtIndexPath and heightForRowAtIndexPath methods.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSNumber * key = [NSNumber numberWithInt:indexPath.row];
    UITableViewCell *cell = [cells objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    UIView * v = [[[cell contentView] subviews] objectAtIndex:0];
    UIImageView  * image = [[v subviews] objectAtIndex:0]; 

    _tappedIndex = [key intValue];
    _expanded = [_tappedCells objectForKey:key] == nil;
    NSLog(@"view's old params: %@", [GGStackPanel printFrameParams:v]); //prints out the frame params
    NSLog(@"image's old params: %@", [GGStackPanel printFrameParams:image]);
    if (_expanded)
    {
        [_tappedCells setObject:key forKey:key];
        v.frame = CGRectMake(v.frame.origin.x, v.frame.origin.y, v.frame.size.width, v.frame.size.height*1.5);
        image.frame = CGRectMake(image.frame.origin.x, image.frame.origin.y, image.frame.size.width, v.frame.size.height + 73);
    }
    else
    {
        [_tappedCells removeObjectForKey:key];
        v.frame = CGRectMake(v.frame.origin.x, v.frame.origin.y, v.frame.size.width, v.frame.size.height/1.5 );
        image.frame = CGRectMake(image.frame.origin.x, image.frame.origin.y, image.frame.size.width, v.frame.size.height - 113);
    }
    NSLog(@"view's new params: %@", [GGStackPanel printFrameParams:v]);
    NSLog(@"image's new params: %@", [GGStackPanel printFrameParams:image]);

    [tableView beginUpdates];
    [tableView endUpdates];
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tv heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *v = [_cells objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    CGFloat height = v.frame.size.height;
    if (indexPath.row == _tappedIndex)
    {
        if (_expanded)
        {
            height = v.frame.size.height * 1.5;
        }

        else
        {
            height = v.frame.size.height/1.5;
        }
    }
    return height;
}
```

The cell frame and V's are expanding, I logged their frame parameters. But the imageView always stays the same, even if you change its frame at each cell selection. Its frame changes while in didSelectRowAtIndexPath method, but when you tap on the same cell again, it says that its frame hasn't change from last time.

If I put another UIView instead of an imageView, it expands and shrinks with its parent View and cell. Thus, I came up with really odd solution: cut the rounded rectangle, leave narrow top and bottom parts as imageView. Then put a blank UIView in the middle, with same color as a rectangle. Now my "rectangle" is expanding, because the blank UIView expands and those two imageViews are shifting up and down. I don't like this solution, because UI gets messed up if you turn your phone to landscape mode, or try to expand a cell from landscape mode and go back to portrait.

Any comments, suggestions?

Comment: can you do all this in IB, setting the content modes and auto-size attributes of the cell's view hierarchy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UIImage view has the same size as its image if you use initWithImage:. I assume that you're adding the image in IB, so I'm guessing that IB uses that method to fill the image view. If you can't add the image after the expansion (with setImage which will cause the image to fill the size of the image view), then I would just use a UIView with rounded corners. You don't need to do the slicing, just use a layer with rounded corners. This is what I've done to make a cell have a grouped look, by putting a rounded white rectangle inside a cell. This is the init method for the subview:

```
-(id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder {
    if (self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder]) {
        self.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        CALayer *bgLayer = self.layer;
        [bgLayer setMasksToBounds:YES];
        [bgLayer setCornerRadius:8];
    }
    return  self;
}
```

Be sure to import the QuartzCore framework if you do this.

Comment: thanks for a solution, worked for me. I am a rookie in iOS development, not familiar with QuartzCore framework. 
You know, I tried to programmatically change the height of UIImageView in a sample project. I can actually do that, if it is not bounded by tableCell, I just set the image mode "to Scale to Fill" in IB. So UIImageView's frame is changeable. Still can't figure out why resizing didn't happen in my case, where imageView is in a view, which is in contentView of cell.